# How do I make only a portion of my shader to be bumpy?

Tags: shaders

I'm using procedural shading at a beginner level. So i wanted to sort of mask out where the lava is. How do I do that?

[image: I only want the "rocky" part to be bumpy and not the lava itself]

Comment: how does your final result should look like?

Comment: Basically, only the "rocky" or cooled lava part should be bumpy/ or look like rocks. The hots lava (orange parts) should look smooth or less bumpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to invert the output of your *Color Ramp* and plug it into the *Strength* input of your *Bump* node.